# SharePoint 2010 Updates, do I need to run all?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cumulative-update, hotfix

So the SharePoint 2010 we are currently working with is version 14.0.6029.1000 which is the June 2011 Update from here -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff800847.aspx.

I need to update SP2010 and there are about 10 updates listed on that page. Do I need to run each one separately or will the latest one contain all the other updates/fixes??

I have read one of the updates and it says "This cumulative update package contains all the .msp files that we released as hotfixes or as public updates that target SharePoint Server 2010. This update package also targets SharePoint Foundation 2010. Therefore, you do not have to install that package separately.", so does that mean 'yes' all updates/fixes before it are included?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a technical perspective strictly:

.6029-1000 indicates you are on service pack 1 as referenced at:

http://www.sharepointdesignerstepbystep.com/blog/SitePages/SharePoint%20versions.aspx

(very handy guide to SharePoint versions up there)

Therefore you can legitimately run any cumulative update between the one following Service Pack 1 (aka the June 2011 CU) and the present (as of yet no Service Pack 2 for SharePoint 2010 has been released, otherwise depending on the SP2 reviews I might say go straight there).

Also, you run your chosen cumulative update "straight away" with no prior cumulative updates being pre-requisites.  Each cumulative update is a rollup of everything after the Service Pack release and only requires that the prior Service Pack be installed.

Which ones should you run?  Tough call depending on your organization's policies regarding Service Packs vs. Cumulative updates (if existent) and the role of the servers to be updated (People tend to be a bit more stringent if applying updates to a production server vs. a development server).  Read more about each cumulative update in the various Internet articles out there and plan your strategy accordingly.